# Excel IndexMatch Between Two Workbooks

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to automate a tedious procedure of transferring incoming calls numbers per hour from one workbook to another. I would like to use the Index Match function for this procedure but unsure on how to approach this.

2 images are attached. Essentially I need to copy the numbers from Queue 1,2,3 and match them to their corresponding destination. The call numbers from Queues 1,2,3 are dynamic - calls are presented at various times during the day. The destination ranges are static - $B59:$B78 for Queue1, $B83 - $B102 for Queue 2 and $B107 - $B126 for Queue 3. If someone could help, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One trick is to name the ranges which makes the index match shorter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a Look at the function CHOOSE. Because your destination ranges are always the same, depending on queue number you may select one destination range or another.